# Links between projects in Project Web Access

Tags: project-server, project-web-access

Does anyone know if the "Links Between Projects" functionality works with projects loaded within Project Web Access?

When i load the dialog the browse button is disabled.

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7493/croppercapture9q.jpg](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7493/croppercapture9q.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "projects loaded within Project Web Access". However you can certainly link tasks between projects stored in Project Server. To do this, open the projects containing the tasks to link, then [follow these instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project/HP452952071033.aspx).